# Jest, React test - Component definition is missing display name

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

Im getting the the error: **Component definition is missing display name** in my react **jest test**. I found different questions and answers about this but none of this answers were useful for my test. Did someone experience the same error and know how to fix it?
Here is my code:

```
const mockPdfCountriesTable = jest.fn();
jest.mock(
  '@components/admin/PdfReport/PdfCountriesPage/PdfCountriesPageTable',
  () => (props) => {
    mockPdfCountriesTable(props);
    return <mockPdfCountriesTable />;
  }
);

describe('PdfReport', () => {
  let wrapper;
  let sortedCountries;
  let attendeeCountries;
  beforeEach(() => {
    const scaleLinear = jest.fn();
    const geoMercator = jest.fn();
    const getSupportedLanguage = jest.fn();
    scaleLinear();
    geoMercator();
    getSupportedLanguage();
    attendeeCountries = {
      US: {
        value: 3324,
        alpha3: 'USA',
      },
      RU: {
        value: 90,
        alpha3: 'RUS',
      },
      CN: {
        value: 675,
        alpha3: 'CHN',
      },
    };
    sortedCountries = [
      {
        value: 3324,
        alpha3: 'USA',
      },
      {
        value: 675,
        alpha3: 'CHN',
      },
      {
        value: 90,
        alpha3: 'RUS',
      },
    ],
    wrapper = mount(
      <PdfCountriesPage attendeeCountries={attendeeCountries} />
    );
  });
  it('Renders <PdfCountriesPageTable/> child component props', () => {
    expect(mockPdfCountriesTable).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      expect.objectContaining({
        sortedCountriesArray: sortedCountries,
      })
    );
  });
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The displayName property is used to give a descriptive name for the React devtools extension and as you are running a test, this is not needed. Therefore the simplest way to remove the error is to mark this function so that eslint ignores the missing displayName. To do this you can add the following comment directly above the `jest.fn()` line:

`// eslint-disable-next-line react/display-name`

So, for your test you would change it to:

```js
const mockPdfCountriesTable = jest.fn();
// eslint-disable-next-line react/display-name
jest.mock(
  '@components/admin/PdfReport/PdfCountriesPage/PdfCountriesPageTable',
  () => (props) => {
    mockPdfCountriesTable(props);
    return <mockPdfCountriesTable />;
  }
);
```

There are other ways around this, but for simplicity in the test I would just comment it out. If you want more detailed info, check out this post, which is how I came across this solution:
https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-component-is-missing-display-name

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Disabling an eslint rule is never a good solution for an issue like this which **will** come up over and over throughout the course of a project as you write component tests. Also, you should avoid testing props as in your example since that is an implementation detail, you should use RTL if possible but that is another story.

Anyway, one suggestion I have is this:

```
jest.mock(
  '@components/admin/PdfReport/PdfCountriesPage/PdfCountriesPageTable',
  () => {
    const MockTable = (props) => (
      // return mock UI
    )
    return MockTable;
  }
);
```

This will make it so the display name is MockTable and you will not have to disable useful eslint rules.